# Angular - How to import a scss variable file using ngc -w?

Tags: angular, sass, tsconfig, angular-compiler-cli

I've got a `FooComponent` that has a `.scss` file attached to it, this works.

However, when trying to import a variable file from an external lib residing in `node_modules`, it throws an error.

In my `.scss` file I do:

```
@import './node_modules/@my-lib/dist/utils/_exports';
```

But when I run `ngc -w tsconfig-aot.json` it throws:

```
Couldn't resolve resource ./node_modules/@my-lib/dist/utils/_exports from /Users/chrillewoodz/my-project/@my-lib/ng/src/components/foo/foo.component.scss
```

The strange thing is that if I do `ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json` (notice the `-p` instead of `-w`) then it works.

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you are inside the component, ./node_modules will look inside the component folder, no ?

Comment: @David I don't think so since using `-p` works correctly. I have tried many other paths as well but none of them work. So I don't think the problem is with the path itself :/

Comment: try using `~` instead of `./node_modules/` like this `'~@my-lib/dist/utils/_exports'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was as simple as having to use both `-w` and `-p`, the `-p` is for explicitly telling `ngc` which config to use. So without it it was using the default `tsconfig.json` file.